# Sawtooth Transaction Processor message

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-sawtooth

I am getting an error like

> Did not respond to the ping, removing transaction processor.

Can anyone guide what is the error here/ If there is any problem with my set-up?

Comment: Docker? Native Ubuntu? What do the logs say around the time of the error? Did any transactions get processed by the TP prior? Is this a genesis block operation or post-transaction? Did the TP load that did not respond? Did it crash? Is it spinning? Provide more information if you hope to get an answer.

Comment: I am running the validator and transaction processor natively. I tried to fire a very simple transaction after which I got this error and also transaction was not processed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a message from the Hyperledger Sawtooth blockchain's Validator.
A timeout occurred when the Validator was checking connections with all the registered transaction processors.  If a transaction processor does not respond, it is removed from the list.

Some possible causes: the transaction processor (TP) died.  Check that the TP process is still running (check in the Docker container if you are running docker).  Check network connectivity if the TP is on another host or another virtual machine.  Check the message logs.  Perhaps the TP is "frozen" or hanging or has a bug.  Add logging messages (using LOGGER).

Comment: Hey Dan.. thanx for your reply. I am running it natively and I got the error when I tried to fire a transaction. My guess is there is some issue with my client. Can you guide me in a direction as to how to write a sawtooth client with an example. The sawtooth official documentation example code is not clear.

Comment: Thanks alot Dan. There were some bugs in transaction processor code.

Comment: @Mouazzam did you report the bugs back to the project? I am seeing the same behavior submitting transactions in an Ubuntu 16.04 VM. All works as expected in my MacOS environment.

Comment: @kblmfld no I did not report it. You can go ahead and add the defect.